# Transform an image into a circle

Tags: javascript, html, image

I'm trying to convert a "squared" image to a circle one.
The image is 48x48,its borders are squared.

I want to crop it with HTML/Javascript/CSS,to turn it into a circle.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Put that image as a div's `background-image` then set the `border-radius` of the div to `50%`. Simple is that. :)

[Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/buPDd/2/)

**CSS of the div:**

```
div {
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
    background: url(your_image_url.your_image_extension);
    border-radius: 50%; /*the magic*/
}
```

Comment: Oooh sweeet!Thanks Mohammad!  
I just used "border-radius: 50%" and it worked great ;)  
It wasn't necessary to put the image as background-image.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use just **javascript** this would work:

```
<img src='.../images/myImage.png' id="id">
<script>
document.getElementById('id').style.borderRadius = '50%';
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to put the image into an editor and then cut the corners of the squares. Therefore, the part you don't want needs to be transparent. When you will put it in a webpage, the transparent part will inherit the color from behind.

Comment: i would go with this approach because border-radius is not supported in earlier versions of IE

Comment: Right, but the OP wanted an HTML/JS/CSS solution.

Comment: @DanyKhalife for css3 support in IE you could try this => https://github.com/lojjic/PIE

Comment: @ConstableJoe yup i agree, but im just pointing out that i think this is better :)

Comment: Not wanting to rain on anyone's parade, but those earlier versions of IE, aren't those the same versions that had troubles with transparency in PNG files? Of course, the OP never said the picture wasn't a GIF...

Comment: I know about that,but the image is gotten via an API,so I can't just cut it in a image editor.

Comment: If you're worried about compatibility with browsers that don't support `border-radius`, you can also do the transformation server-side. It'll be a little more work though.

Comment: @MrLister: IE 6 and earlier didn’t support alpha transparency in PNG files. IE 7 and later do.